# Device LDAP Authenticable using group within cn?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Im trying to set up a Devise Authenticable LDAP login system. Right now, I can get it to work using all users. However, i would like to only use users within a certain group. To illustrate, as of now, using all users, the code looks like this:

```
production:
  host: my.host.domain.com
  port: 389
  attribute: AccountName
  base: cn=users,dc=my,dc=con,dc=to,dc=host
  admin_user: adminuser
  admin_password: password
  ssl: false
```

So the following is the code i wrote to make it only work within the group "demo2" located within users. However, now it doesnt work with ANY user... Any suggestions?

```
 production:
  host: my.host.domain.com
  port: 389
  attribute: AccountName
  base: cn=demo2,cn=users,dc=my,dc=con,dc=to,dc=host
  admin_user: adminuser
  admin_password: password
  ssl: false
```

Comment: Can you see any errors in the LDAP log?

Comment: @Devin No, i was looking for the ldap log, where is it?

Comment: What LDAP server are you using and which OS?

Comment: @devin Active Directory on freeBSD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to use `required_groups` in your ldap.yml.  If you look at the [template file](https://github.com/cschiewek/devise_ldap_authenticatable/blob/master/lib/generators/devise_ldap_authenticatable/templates/ldap.yml) you can see the example:

```
group_base: ou=groups,dc=test,dc=com
## Requires config.ldap_check_group_membership in devise.rb be true
  # Can have multiple values, must match all to be authorized required_groups:
  # If only a group name is given, membership will be checked against "uniqueMember"
  - cn=admins,ou=groups,dc=test,dc=com
```

Comment: but that problem is i think that is expeciting the group to use a OU, but all have cn within cn..